# ICloud will not sync icloud documents across Mac OS devices: likely cause and solution

Tags: macos, ios, icloud

I have had this iCloud sync problem three times over a two year period on the same MacBookPro.  The documents in iCloud comprised about 200 GB of data in around 100,000 files.  Largish, but not unduly so. In each case i finally went to Applecare. Attempted solutions included variously many of the steps highlighted on this forum, and more: deleting all the iCloud files; reinstalling the OS; wiping the mac clean and a complete fresh reinstall Off everything.  In all three cases the issue was escalated to their enginsc sharing with a specialist, downloaded apple diagnostic software; screen recordings to shew how files wouldn’t upload. On the first two occasions after a week or so it seemed to just get fixed, but no advice as to what was the cause. Whilst am currently waiting for apple to revert on the current downtime, I think I’ve cracked it.

We were using iCloud to share documents within a small company. That and Dropbox were our non MS Exchange server equivalents.  As we are planning on phasing out DB, when iCloud failed I tried out OneDrive.  Have to admit have not been a great fan of MS products in recent years, having converted the whole office to Mac 8 years ago.  But OneDrive came with a 1TB capacity as part of the Office subscription so it was worth a try.  On migrating files OneDrive flagged hundreds (approx 800) files as not capable of syncing due to file name violations (e.g. questions marks in the file name; file name starting with a space; various misc characters such as | etc). The 1D software makes it easy to go to the problem files and rename them, a process that took less than a couple of hours and appears to have solved the issue.  I don’t know of any other software that lets you know so quickly of problems with file names, but maybe there is one out there.  iCloud unfortunately doesn’t.  The Dropbox literature warns of the potential issues with illegal file names, but does not flag those files that violate the rules.  Certainly it’s a tweak that Apple could usefully employ within iCloud.

As a test therefore, try moving across docs to a (free, no point in wasting money) trial or listed version of OneDrive to see if it flags up any badly named files. Way faster than manually reviewing them. And the amount of tech support time it would have saved... not to mention the productivity...

Comment: What is your question? I must have missed it.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. If you read the [tour] and [help] it will show how we love people to answer their questions. Just take all the answer in to the answer section and edit this down so the question is clear and easy to understand. Thanks for contributing!